# Gson setDateFormat thows exception when date is null

Tags: date, gson, kotlin

I have built my Gson instance as :

```
val DATE_FORMAT_MASK = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_MASK)
        .create()
```

This work properly until I execute the serialization of a null date

```
gson.toJson(null, Date::class.java)
```

Then I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:88)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
```

How I can handle this situation ?

May be a bug in Gson library ?

Comment: I answer my own question, but every comment/feedback/alternative/improvement are very welcomed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, the issue was present in version 2.8.1 of Gson. Either going back to 2.8.0 or forward to 2.8.2 fixes the issue. If you're stuck on 2.8.1, there is [another workaround](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1096#issuecomment-324931546) detailed in this bug report: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1096

```
private Gson getGson() {
  // Trick to get the DefaultDateTypeAdatpter instance
  // Create a first instance a Gson
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_COMPLETE)
    .create();

  // Get the date adapter
  TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(Date.class);

  // Ensure the DateTypeAdapter is null safe
  TypeAdapter<Date> safeDateTypeAdapter = dateTypeAdapter.nullSafe();

  // Build the definitive safe Gson instance
  return new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, safeDateTypeAdapter)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, by the date didn't find the related issue :)

Answer (score 3):

I really amazed that `setDateFormat` does not handle null serialization. I think you are forced to implement type adapters:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
        //.setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_MASK)
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java, JsonSerializer<Date> { date: Date?, type, context ->
            val parsed = date?.toString(DATE_FORMAT_MASK)
            if(parsed == null) null
            else context?.serialize(parsed)

        })
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java, JsonDeserializer<Date> { json: JsonElement?, type, context ->
            json?.asString?.toDate(DATE_FORMAT_MASK)
        })
        .create()
```

Where `toDate` and `toString` are:

```
fun Date.toString(mask: String): String? {
    try {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(mask, Locale.getDefault())
        return simpleDateFormat.format(this)
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        return null
    }
}

fun String.toDate(mask: String): Date? {
    return try {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(mask, Locale.getDefault())
        simpleDateFormat.parse(this)
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

This cover te following test:

```
data class DateWrapper(val date: Date?)

@Test fun date_serialization() {

    val deserializedDate = gson.fromJson("\"2017-10-23T12:48:43+0200\"", Date::class.java)
    assertNotNull(deserializedDate)

    val deserializedNullDate = gson.fromJson("null", Date::class.java)
    assertNull(deserializedNullDate)

    val deserializedNullDate2 = gson.fromJson("", Date::class.java)
    assertNull(deserializedNullDate2)


    val deserializedDateWrapper = gson.fromJson("{date: null}", DateWrapper::class.java)
    assertNull(deserializedDateWrapper.date)

    val deserializedDateWrapper2 = gson.fromJson("{date: \"\"}", DateWrapper::class.java)
    assertNull(deserializedDateWrapper2.date)

    val deserializedDateWrapper3 = gson.fromJson("{}", DateWrapper::class.java)
    assertNull(deserializedDateWrapper3.date)


    val serializedDate = gson.toJson(Date(), Date::class.java)
    assertNotNull(serializedDate)

    val serializedNullDate = gson.toJson(null, Date::class.java)
    assertEquals("null", serializedNullDate)

    val date = Date()
    val serializedDateWrapper = gson.toJson(DateWrapper(date), DateWrapper::class.java)
    assertNotNull(serializedDateWrapper)

    val serializedDateWrapper2 = gson.toJson(DateWrapper(null), DateWrapper::class.java)
    assertNotNull(serializedDateWrapper2)
}
```